# Porque a imagem não está apagando com unlink?

Tags: php

Eu tenho um método que está assim :

```
public function setPhoto($file)
    {

        $extension = explode('.', $file['name']);
        $extension = end($extension);

        switch ($extension) {

            case "jpg":
            case "jpeg":
            $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file["tmp_name"]);
            break;

            case "gif":
            $image = imagecreatefromgif($file["tmp_name"]);
            break;

            case "png":
            $image = imagecreatefrompng($file["tmp_name"]);
            break;

        }

        $dist = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 
            "upload" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 
            "img" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 
            "products". DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 
            $this->getidproduct() . ".jpg";

        $verify = $dist;    

        if(isset($verify)){
           unlink($verify); 
        }   

        imagejpeg($image, $dist);

        imagedestroy($image);

        $this->checkPhoto();

    }





public function checkPhoto()
    {

        if (file_exists(


            $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 
            "upload" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 
            "img" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 
            "products" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 
            $this->getidproduct() . ".jpg"


            )) {

            $url = "/upload/img/products/" . $this->getidproduct() . ".jpg";

        } else {

            $url = "/upload/img/products/product.jpg";

        }

        $this->setdesphoto($url);

        return $this->setdesphoto($url);

    }
```

Básicamente ele cria uma imagem, e salva numa pasta qualquer. No meu site, quando vou atualizar uma imagem, ele chama esse método para setar a imagem, e depois usa o CheckPhoto para quando for verificar as imagens e mandar a url

A minha duvida é a seguinte, eu seto uma imagem, aparece no meu site tranquilo, quando vou setar outra imagem, a segunda imagem não aparece, e em vez disso ainda continua aparecendo a primeira. Verifico na pasta que foi salva a imagem, e lá está salva a segunda normalmente, só que fica aparecendo a primeira, o que pode ser isso? Eu até deletei a primeira imagem da pasta, mas continua aparecendo.

Comment: `var_dump($verify);` na linha acima do unlink mostra o que ? O valor mostrado existe como caminho ?

Comment: Ele mostra basicamente o caminho da variavel dist que fiz em cima. E sim, o caminho existe, e ele vai lá e apaga a img da pasta. Então vou setar outra imagem no site, olho na pasta e está lá a segunda imagem salva na pasta, porém quando vou olhar no site, ainda está a primeira imagem.

Comment: mas você confirma que a imagem existe pelo site ou pelo cpanel ? Convem confirmar na fonte mesmo, pois pode ser que o seu código de visualização tenha problemas também.

Comment: Eu confirmo baseado que quando olho na basta htdocs/uploads/   a nova imagem está lá salva, e a antiga está na lixeira já kkk E quando eu vou olhar ainda está a antiga. Obs: o codigo para visualizar nada mais é que a variavel $dist, ou seja, na imagem eu só boto um<img src=" < ?php echo $dist ?>" >  , a variavel dist é o caminho da imagem, entendeu?

Answer (score -2):

você tem certeza o problema não está no cache do seu navegador? pois, se a imagem é apagada e a nova imagem aparece na pasta porém não aparece no navegador só pode ser o cache do navegador que continua exibindo a antiga. Ou limpa o cache do seu navegador ou tenta abrir em outro.

Comment: Isto não responde à pergunta. Quando você tiver [reputação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) suficiente, você vai poder deixar [comentários em qualquer post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) mas, até lá, escreva apenas resposta que não [dependam de mais informações de quem perguntou](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/266832)

Comment: mas não precisa de mais informações: "Ele mostra basicamente o caminho da variavel dist que fiz em cima. E sim, o caminho existe, e ele vai lá e apaga a img da pasta. Então vou setar outra imagem no site, olho na pasta e está lá a segunda imagem salva na pasta, porém quando vou olhar no site, ainda está a primeira imagem."

Comment: Sua resposta está mais para um comentário. Veja que ela começa com uma pergunta: "_você tem certeza o problema não está no cache do seu navegador?_"... como diz a revisão: "_escreva apenas resposta que não dependam de mais informações de quem perguntou_". A resposta não é conclusiva, ela está mais para uma suposição.